# Why is this constexpr function giving different results under different circumstances in gcc?

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, constexpr

So I have the following simple snippet:

```
template <typename T, size_t size>
struct SquareMatrix {
public:
    T data[size * size];
    constexpr T & operator()(const size_t row, const size_t col) noexcept {
        return data[row * size + col];
    }
};

constexpr auto generate() {
    auto result = SquareMatrix<int, 2>{};
    result(0, 0) = 1;
    result(1, 0) = 3;
    result(0, 1) = 2;
    result(1, 1) = 4;
    return result;
}
```

The expected contents of the `data` array in the `SquareMatrix<int, 2>` produced by `generate()` is `1, 2, 3, 4`. However...

```
constexpr auto test = generate();

int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout << test.data[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run this code using g++ 5.2 and `-std=c++14`, the result that is printed to the console is, bizarrely, `1032`.

If remove the constexpr qualifiers so it executes at runtime, or if I instead write either of the following slight variations:

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto test = generate();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout << test.data[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

... or ...

```
constexpr auto generate() {
    auto result = SquareMatrix<int, 2>{};
    result(0, 0) = 1;
    result(0, 1) = 2; // this line and
    result(1, 0) = 3; // this line have been swapped
    result(1, 1) = 4;
    return result;
}

constexpr auto test = generate();

int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout << test.data[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

... the expected result, `1234`, is printed. Additionally, clang++ 3.7.0 prints the expected `1234` in all cases.

Have I hit a g++ bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks related to the gcc bug [[5 regression] Constant expression factory function initializes std::array with static storage duration strangely](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67104) and if we try this with [gcc head live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jVqSo8nM7y0tmRpo) it works fine.

The bug report has the following similar example, where the static variable case exhibits a similar issue while the automatic variable case does not:

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

namespace /* anonymous */
{

  constexpr auto
  make_array(const int val) noexcept
  {
    std::array<int, 2> result = { { val, 0 } };
    return result;
  }

  // Replacing `constexpr` by `const` doesn't change anything.
  constexpr auto numbers_static = make_array(42);

}

int main()
{
  const auto numbers_automatic = make_array(42);
  assert(numbers_automatic[0] == 42);  // okay
  assert(numbers_static[0] == 42);     // fails
}
```